# What cause WriteFile api call to be reported with I/O flags "Paging I/O" and "Synchronous Paging I/O" in Process Monitor?

Tags: c++, winapi, ntfs, writefile, createfile

I am monitoring the I/O operations of a Win32 application (not written by me) with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and trying to replicate the behavior of `WriteFile` with a C++ program (eg: my `WriteFile` calls would produce same logs in Process Monitor).

The `WriteFile` calls are reported with I/O flags "*Non-cached*, *Paging I/O* and *Synchronous Paging I/O*".
*Non-cached* is easy to replicate : if I add the [FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#parameters) attribute to `CreateFile` `dwFlagsAndAttributes` parameter: all the `WriteFile` calls will be reported that way.

I am trying to find out what is causing *Paging I/O* to be seen in Process Monitor and how to replicate it.

Comment: Paging I/O comes from OS internal paging (where virtual memory is swapped from disk to physical memory or the other way around). Triggered by page faults;

Comment: @PepijnKramer : that's weird because when it happen, memory usage is like 50%. I would expect page faults to occurs with a higher memory usage than that.

Comment: High memory usage would probably result in more paging, but Windows uses the paging file for many things even in normal situations.

Comment: An API monitor such as Rohit will show the actual function parameters, as well as exactly what function is being called (there are many more functions that write to open files than just `WriteFile`)